# Can't add gcc-arm-linux-gnueabhf version 7 to Ubuntu

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-16.04, raspberry-pi3, cross-compiling

- I'm trying to compile u-boot for Raspberry pi 3 but I have an issue
  with my cross-compiler on my Ubuntu 16.04. I installed gcc-arm-linux-gnueabhf with sudo apt-get install, it automatically
  installed version 4.8.
- When I ran make CROSS_COMPILe=arm-linux-gnueabhf- to make u-boot
  files, make erros and said that it needs arm-linux-gnueabhf higher version>= 6. To solve this, I downloaded a new 7.4 version and add
  it's path to ~/.bashrc file.

> export
>   PATH="$PATH:/home/$USER/opt/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin"

- I run command arm-linux-gnueabhf-gcc --version. It still in 4.8.
  Please help me look into it.

========================================================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The issue was solved with reference form
  https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-ARMCrossCompiler:GCC